# Terminator - command not found

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, terminator

I am new to Linux and installed Terminator. While i can perform basic commands like cd, ls etc no application command will work. npm , sh, foreman for example all say command not found or the likes. 
Any suggestions?

```
laptop:/home/nigel/devproxy$ ./start
./start: line 8: node: command not found
```

Comment: But it works in `gnome-terminal` ?

Comment: yes works fine in gnome-terminal

Comment: Did you enable "run as login shell" in gnome-terminal?

Comment: in gnonme-terminal and terminator i have 'run as login shell' checked on.

Answer (score 0):

If it is newly installed, there is a chance that none these programs are installed. Once a new program is installed, it will be added to PATH of that user and he can summon the app directly from the terminal.

**'Node'** may not be installed in your linux. terminal cannot identify a node program.
Lets say you need to use **'curl'** command on terminal to download some data from a url. if curl is not installed, it will give same error.
So, following command install curl from repositories.

```
$ sudo apt install curl
```

During installation, the path to curl is added to your path. and you will be able to use curl command by directly using the command as

```
$ curl https://www.google.com
```